# Simple_Form nesting expected Array (got String) for param `answer_ids'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form, has-many-through, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I want a user to be able to fill out multiple choice questions on a form. The form consists of Multiple Surveys, each with multiple questions (and each question is multiple choice)

I can't seem to store the multiple survey bit. I want a answer_ids which I can then save on a User has_many Answers Through: :user_answer relationship. But I'm struggling.

I get the following error:

> expected Array (got String) for param `answer_ids'

Here's my form:

```
<%= simple_form_for [current_user], :url => competition_enter_path, :method => :POST do |u| %>
  <% @surveys.each do |survey| %>
    <%= u.simple_fields_for [survey] do |f| %>

        <div class="contnt1">


        <%= survey.name %>
        <br />
             <% survey.questions.each do |qq| %>
              <%= f.simple_fields_for qq do |q| %>
                      <h3><%= qq.question %></h3>
                      <%=   q.association :answers,
                                          label: false,
                                          collection: qq.answers,
                                          as: :"#{qq.question_type.code}",
                                          :label_method => :answer,
                                          required: true
                      %>
                      <% end %>
                   <% end %>
                </div>

          <% end %>
    <% end %>
        <div class="actions">
          <%= u.submit %>
        </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same problem. I sort of fixed by replacing:

```
collection: qq.answers,
```

with:

```
collection: qq.answers.map{|v| [v.property_for_answer_text, v]}
```

As far as I can tell, the problem is that the value that the form sees is a string and not an Answer object. And thus it tries to send String where it should be Answer object.